# Postgresql : null value as query input in java native query throws operator does not exist: character varying = bytea exception

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, null, hibernate-native-query

i have a query where i check first if the input parameter(`list<string>`) is null or i set the condition to pass input parameter in where condition of the query

Ex:

```
@Query(value = SELECT * FROM employee t WHERE (((:employeeNameList) is  null) or  ((:employeeNameList) is not null and t.emp_name  IN (:employeeNameList) )", nativeQuery = true) 

Page<Employee> findAllData(Pageable pageable, @Param("employeeNameList")List<String> employeeNameList);
```

the above query is failing when i pass null value as input with the below error

> ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bytea Hint: No
>   operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need
>   to add explicit type casts.  Position: 126".

It works fine when i pass list which contain some string values.